# Error Training FeedForward Neural Network With Various Type of Variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization, neural-networks, mxnet-format

I built the following FeedForward NN

```
net = NetGraph[{CatenateLayer[], 200, DropoutLayer[], Ramp, 100,  
DropoutLayer[], Ramp , 100, BatchNormalizationLayer[] , 
LogisticSigmoid, 50, DropoutLayer[],  Ramp,  2,  
SoftmaxLayer[]}, {NetPort["Input"] -> 
1, {NetPort["Ethnicity"], NetPort["Gender"], NetPort["Physical"], 
 NetPort["Mental"]} -> 
 1 -> 2 -> 
  3 -> 4 -> 
    5 -> 6 -> 
      7 -> 8 -> 
        9 -> 10 -> 
          11 -> 12 -> 13 -> 14 -> 15 -> NetPort["Output"]
 },
 "Gender" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", gender, "UnitVector"}],
 "Physical" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", {"0", "1"}, "UnitVector"}],
 "Mental" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", {"0", "1"}, "UnitVector"}],
 "Ethnicity" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", ethnicity, "UnitVector"}],
 "Input" -> 4,
"Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {"non", "yes"}}]]
```

[image]

MY data are as follows:

```
 {<|"Ethnicity" -> "Caucasian", "Gender" -> "Female", 
   "Physical" -> "0", "Mental" -> "1", 
   "Input" -> {-4.2168, 0.285714, -0.364365, -1.41703}, 
   "Output" -> "yes"|>, 
  <|"Ethnicity" -> "Black", "Gender" -> "Female",
   "Physical" -> "1", "Mental" -> "0", 
   "Input" -> {-0.44976, 0.142857, 0.204846, 0.16707}, 
   "Output" -> "yes"|>}
```

I initialize the model, I tried my data:

```
  netDrop = NetInitialize[net]
  netDrop[tDate2[[100, 1 ;; 5]]]

  Out[180]= "yes"
```

But when I try to train it, I get the following error:
       trainTmp =  NetTrain[netDrop, tDate2]

NetTrain::encgenfail2: Could not encode one or more inputs for port "Ethnicity": supplied data was a 10*7 matrix of real numbers, but expected a class. The invalid inputs had indices {1,8,3,6,7,2,9,4,5,10}.

But ethnicity is set with:

```
   DeleteDuplicates[tDate2[[All, "Ethnicity"]]]
```

and returns:

```
   {"Caucasian", "Black", "Hispanic", "Asian", "Native American", 
  "Other", "South East Asian"}
```

I'm at loss.  I've no idea what to do.  I'm sure it is something extremely simple.

Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in another link:

```
 NeuralNetworks`Private`ReinitializeNeuralNetworks[]; 
 DeleteDirectory[#, DeleteContents -> True] & /@ 
 FileNames[
 FileNameJoin@{"*", #} & /@ {"NeuralNetworks*", "MXNetLink*"}, 
 FileNameJoin@{$CacheBaseDirectory, 
   "PacletCachedData"}];
```

(*Then Quit and try again.This will delete \
internal definitions for the neural net framework that we cache \
locally to speed up loading times.Maybe those local files got \
corrupted. [Dash]Matteo Salvarezza*)